# Latest China devaluation (24/08/2015) and the affect on house prices in UK

Tags: stock-markets, housing

Are there any strong bases for worry that house prices will fall considering the latest FTSE 100 issues regarding China... and todays (25/08/2015) slight rise.

This is regarding house prices in the UK.

What kind of research might i want to perform to make sure purchasing a house at this point in time will be or not be a bad decision?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.
There is no indication that the recent decline will have an impact on the house market in the UK.
The reason(s) for the downward move these last few weeks are mainly due to:

- Unclear direction in regards to first Fed rate hike in many years.
- Chinese economy growing slower than expected.
- Extremely overbought region in which the stocks were located.

The last two points caused the Chinese government to decide to *devaluate* the Yuan. This in turn triggered an unforeseen panic attack among investors and speculators around the globe starting with the Chinese that are trading on borrowed money (not only on margin but also by using loans).

The UK house prices are not influenced by the above factors, not even indirectly.
The most important factors for house prices are in general:

- Interest rates
- Population
- Income
- Trust
- Mortgages

If you keep the above points in mind you should be able to decide whether now is the right time to buy a house in your area.
Given that a lot of central banks ([incl. BoE](http://uk.businessinsider.com/bank-of-england-boe-ben-broadbent-on-uk-interest-rate-rise-date-2015-8)) are maintaining a low interest rate policy (except fed soon), now is a good time to take a mortgage.

Sources used:

- http://econ.economicshelp.org/2007/09/what-determines-house-prices.html
- Own (limited) trading experience

### Additional info

I know interest rates are determined by the BoE which looks at the global picture to determine these rates but the main directive of a central bank is to maintain an inflation close to but not exactly 2 % as to spur on economic growth. 
As such, the value of a company as valuated on the stock market is not or barely taken into account.

The negligible impact is the reason why I stated that the crash in the summer of 2015 doesn't even have an indirect impact. 
Also such a crash is very short lived. It's more the underlying reason for the fears that could cause issues if they drag on.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will leave open for a couple of days for variety in opinion, then mark it as accepted.

Comment: No problem. Hope I informed you clearly enough. Do put this as the answer if you like it and were able to form a decision.